# What is the most accurate way to approximate function value if discrete points are known

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, derivatives, taylor-expansion, partial-derivative

Say, If I have a function $f(x_1, x_2, x_3)$ and I know the value and derivatives of multiple combination of points. e.g. $f(0,0,0)$, $f(1,1,1)$, $f(2,3,4)$, $f(10, 20, 30)$.

What is the best way to calculate $f(5,10,15)$? We can simplify this to $2$ variables or we can ignore $2$nd order partial derivatives impact.

What would be most accurate way of getting the result? Can I do average of derivatives?

Comment: "accurate" has no absolute meaning in this context...*any* value is possible.  What people generally do is to look for a best fit given some (strong) assumptions about the function.

Comment: Polynomial interpolation is a simple, popular choice that will work well if the function isn't doing anything too crazy. The exact form of the interpolant depends on what function values and derivatives you have available. If the function values you have access to may have errors (perhaps because they are measurements), you may want to use some curve fitting method instead.